# get a value from array inside another array

Tags: arrays, swift

i have this input

```
let teachersInfo: [[String]] = [
      ["names", "comments"],
      ["Ian", ",scientist,male, no_available"],
      ["Mark", "teacher,elementary school,female, available_for_new"],
      ["Bryan", "interior designer,male,no_available"],
      ["Tomas", "profesional surfer,master"],
      ["Justine", "no_available, scientist"],
      ["Malek", "teacher, elementary school, available_for_new"],
      ["Adrian", "scientist, profesional surfer, available_for_new"],  
      ["Mike", "elementary schoole,male,no_available"]
    ]
```

how can i make a funtions that returns

```
func findTeachersSkills() -> [String] {
        // TODO: return all names that are profesional surfer
        
        
     
        return []
    }
```

the *names* from the whoever is a **profesional surfer**

then get the *names* from whoever is **teacher** and have **available_for_new**

Comment: you can find the answer here at: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your sample data does not contain the result which fits all your conditions so I add one item into it

```swift
let teachersInfo: [[String]] = [
    ["names", "comments"],
    ["Ian", ",scientist,male, no_available"],
    ["Mark", "teacher,elementary school,female, available_for_new"],
    ["Bryan", "interior designer,male,no_available"],
    ["Tomas", "profesional surfer,master"],
    ["Justine", "no_available, scientist"],
    ["Malek", "teacher, elementary school, available_for_new"],
    ["Adrian", "scientist, profesional surfer, available_for_new"],
    ["Mike", "elementary schoole,male,no_available"],
    ["Johan", "teacher, profesional surfer, available_for_new"]
]
```

And for your question, it can divide into two task: get the list which is fit all your conditions and get the name of it. From your array we can notice that at index 0 is the name and all others are at index 1

Code will be like this

```swift
func findTeachersSkills(_ teachersInfo: [[String]]) -> [String] {
    // TODO: return all names that are profesional surfer
    // get teacher info which is a profesional surfer
    let listTeacherInfoIsProfesionalSurfer = teachersInfo.filter{$0[1].contains("profesional surfer")}
    
    // get teacher info which is teacher and have available_for_new
    let listTeacherInfoIsTeacher = listTeacherInfoIsProfesionalSurfer.filter{$0[1].contains("teacher") && $0[1].contains("available_for_new")}
    
    // Because name in index 0 so return it
    return listTeacherInfoIsTeacher.map{$0[0]}
}
```

We can combine all into one filter like this

```swift
func findTeachersSkills(_ teachersInfo: [[String]]) -> [String] {
    // TODO: return all names that are profesional surfer
    // get teacher info which is a profesional surfer
    // get teacher info which is teacher and have available_for_new
    let listTeacherInfoIsTeacher = teachersInfo.filter{$0[1].contains("profesional surfer") && $0[1].contains("teacher") && $0[1].contains("available_for_new")}
    
    // Because name in index 0 so return it
    return listTeacherInfoIsTeacher.map{$0[0]}
}
```

The result is

```swift
let finalResult = findTeachersSkills(teachersInfo) // ["Johan"]
```

Comment: thank you so much for answer i was getting crazy! will learn more for the future.

Comment: one more question is there a way to search for example instead of .contains something like .notContains? for example
listTeacherInfoIsProfesionalSurfer.filter{$0[1].contains("scientist") && $0[1].NOTCONTAINS("available_for_new")}

Comment: Dear @ZeroCooL, using !$0[1].contains("available_for_new") instead because swift does not have NOTCONTAINS

Comment: feeling so dumb 
listTeacherInfoIsProfesionalSurfer.filter{$0[1].contains("scientist") && !$0[1]. contains("available_for_new")}
just need to add !